# How do I solve: The normal to the curve $\ xe^{-y} + e^{y} = 1 + x$ at the point $(c, \ln c)$ has a $y$-intercept $\ c^2+ 1$. Determine c.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

How do I solve: The normal to the curve $\ xe^{-y} + e^{y} = 1 + x$ at the point $(c, \ln c)$ has a $y$-intercept $\ c^2+ 1$. Determine c.

I tried substituting $\ x=0$ to find out the y-intercept, but it came out to $\ e^y = 1$, which is 0.

I don't understand what I should do. How do I differentiate the left and right sides of the equation?

Comment: The gradient of $f(x, y)=0$ will give you the normal vector to the curve. If you don't know what that is you will need to do implicit differentiation of the expression to find the derivative of y. At the point given you then have the slope of the tangent line. Then you can find the slope and equation of the normal line. With that you can find an equation for c from the intercept information given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting $x = 0$ in $xe^{-y}+ e^y= x+ 1$ gives the $y$-intercept of $xe^{-y}+ e^y= x+ 1$. That is NOT what is asked for! You are asked to find the $y$-intercept of the normal line to that curve at $(c, \ln(c))$. So first you need to find that line!

Differentiating $xe^{-y}+ e^y= x+
 1$ with respect to $x$,

$$e^{-y}- xe^{-y}y'+ e^y y'= 1$$

At $(c, \ln(c))$ that is

$$e^{-\ln(c)}- ce^{-\ln(c)}y'+ e^{\ln(c)}y'= 1$$

$$1/c- c(1/c)y'+ (1/c)y'= (1/c- 1)y'+ 1/c= 1$$

so

$$(1/c- 1)y'= 1- 1/c$$

$$y'= (1-1/c)/(1/c- 1)= -1$$

The tangent line to this curve at $(c, \ln(c))$ has slope $-1$ so the normal line there has slope $1$ and has equation $y= x- c+ \ln(c)$.  The $y$-intercept of **that** line is $(0, \ln(c)- c)$.

Answer (score 0):

You may write the factor $e^{-y}$ as $\frac{1}{e^{y}}$. Then your equation is a quadratic equation in $e^{y}$ with solutions $y = 0$ and $y = \ln(x)$ (which are obvious by inspection).
From the derivative of $y = \ln(x)$, the slope at $x = c$ is thus $1/c$ and the tangent equation at this point is $y = x/c + \ln(c) - 1$. At this same point, the normal line has the equation $y = -x/c + \ln(c) - 1$.
Therefore the y-intercept of the normal line is obtained by setting $x = 0$ and $y = 1 + c^2$, yielding the solution for "c" as $\ln(c) = 2 + c^2$ which can be solved by the Lambert W-function.